# MySQL INSERT Data with conditions: Check if a value exists in another table in order to insert values into a third table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables

1/ liste-articles

[image]

2/ cmd-moy-j

[image]

3/ cmd-medicaments

[image]

4/ cmd-alimentation

[image]

first of all i need to check if a "cmd-moy-j"."Famille" is empty. if so, I need to check if "cmd-moy-j"."Code Article" exists in "cmd-medicaments" or "cmd-alimentation" or "cmd-consommables" tables, in order to add this "Code Article" to a table called "liste-articles". you can see details in the following algorithme

I want to do this: (with only one MySQL request)

> If 'cmd-moy-j.Famille' = "" (is empty)
>
> then{
>
> if ('cmd-moy-j.Code Article' **Exists in** 'cmd-medicaments')
>
> ```
>  then 
>  INSERT a new row to 'liste-articles' table with:
>  liste-articles.Famille = "MEDICAMENT"
>  liste-articles.Code Article = cmd-moy-j.Code Article
> ```
>
> else if ('cmd-moy-j.Code Article' **Exists in** 'cmd-alimentation')
>
> ```
>  then
>  INSERT a new row to 'liste-articles' table with:
>  liste-articles.Famille = "ALIMENTATION"
>  liste-articles.Code Article = cmd-moy-j.Code Article
> ```
>
> else
>        INSERT a new row to 'liste-articles' table with:
>        liste-articles.Famille = "NULLL"
>        liste-articles.Code Article = cmd-moy-j.Code Article 
>   }

Thanks for your help.
Regards.

Comment: Please just explain what you want. I don't need to hack your code before answering your question.

Comment: Give also your expected result schema.

Comment: it's not my code, it's an algorithme that explains what I want

Comment: Explain it in clear english! What do you want as  result? Are you querying the data or do you want to update it?

Comment: @cdaiga I want to update it

Comment: first of all i need to check if a "cmd-moy-j"."Famille"  is empty.
if so, I need to check if "cmd-moy-j"."Code Article" exists in "cmd-medicaments" or "cmd-alimentation" tables, in order to add this "Code Article" to a table called "liste-articles". 
you can see details in my algorithme

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to update all the article list family based on table where the articles are stored. Try this query:

```
UPDATE list-articles A
INNER JOIN cmd-moy-j B ON A.`Code Article`=B.`Code Article`
SET A.Famille=(
  CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cmd-medicaments C 
                    WHERE B.`Code Article`=C.`Code Article` LIMIT 1)
       THEN 'MEDICAMENT'
       WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cmd-alimentation D 
                    WHERE B.`Code Article`=D.`Code Article` LIMIT 1)
       THEN 'ALIMENTATION'
       ELSE 'NULLL'
  END
)
WHERE A.Famille IS NULL OR A.Famille='NULLL' OR A.Famille='';
```

See the following links for insights:

[MySQL CASE Expression](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-function/#)
    [MySQL Join Made Easy](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/)
    [MySQL UPDATE JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/#)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  
I don't want to update all article list family, but to add new articles to "liste-articles" table. (add "Famille" and "Code Article" in each new row)

Comment: @FaresZAIDI you said you wanted to update the article list in one of your comments on your question. So on what criteria is one supposed to add a new article list.

Comment: it was a mistake, I want to ADD a value (insert).

this is my comment: 

first of all i need to check if a "cmd-moy-j"."Famille" is empty. if so, I need to check if "cmd-moy-j"."Code Article" exists in "cmd-medicaments" or "cmd-alimentation" tables, in order to add this "Code Article" to a table called "liste-articles". you can see details in my algorithme

Comment: No it doesn't work, I want to insert new rows to "liste-articles" table, not to update existing ones

Comment: @FaresZAIDI can you create a sample database on [sqlfiddle](www.sqlfiddle.com) ? That way I can test and easily correct my query!